# In how many ways can three balls be selected if no more than two red balls can be included?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

A bag contains 28 balls, 11 red balls, 10 black balls, 7 yellow balls. In how many ways can 3 balls be selected from the bag without replacement, if no more than two red balls can be included in the draw?

I started by laying out all of the combinations:

$$
\begin{array}{lll|lll|lll}
Y & Y & Y & Y & B & Y & Y & R & Y \\
B & Y & Y & B & B & Y & B & R & Y \\
R & Y & Y & R & B & Y & R & R & Y \\
Y & Y & B & Y & B & B & Y & R & B \\
B & Y & B & B & B & B & B & R & B \\
R & Y & B & R & B & B & R & R & B \\
Y & Y & R & Y & B & R & Y & R & R \\
B & Y & R & B & B & R & B & R & R \\
R & Y & R & R & B & R & R & R & R
\end{array} \\
\frac{7}{27}
$$

then I counted the number of times more than two reds are selected which is 1. so the answer should be 26.  Am I wrong here?

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8588/290189)
I have tried to improve the readability of your question by introducing
[$\rm \LaTeX$](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/) while [removing your picture](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189), which may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.. It is possible that I unintentionally changed the meaning of your question.
Please proofread the question to ensure this has not happened.

Comment: Does order matter? Please explain, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

See that when you listed out all the possible combinations, you have counted some of them multiple times ($RBB$ and $BBR$ are the same combination, for example)

In the context of this problem, we have three colors to choose from: red, black, and yellow. Since there are at least three of each type in the bag, we can treat this as picking $3$ balls from three colors where repetition is allowed, but order is not important. This is also referred to as the [Stars and Bars](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) technique.

The total number of ways this can be done is $10$. One of these ways includes the combination $RRR$, which does not meet the requirement of at most $2$ reds. Therefore the total number of ways this can happen is $9$.

This answer can also be found using your method if you remove duplicate combinations.

If the order of how you choose the balls matters, then what you have found is correct.

Comment: Fine but op hasnt said that balls are picked one by one or how etc..

Comment: This is true, but I don't see why the order should matter. If it did, then the OP would be correct in saying there are $26$ ways

Comment: Yes I also think so.

Answer (score 0):

So after getting the answer wrong D: it turns out there are 3276 combinations in total and 165 of those contain 3 red balls so the answer is 3111.

Comment: Ahh, then in this case they assumed the order the balls picked did not matter, but the balls were distinct. (Example: red ball #1, yellow ball #1 black ball #1 is a different combination than red ball #2, yellow ball #1, black ball #3)

Comment: That answer is obtained by selecting the $\binom{11}{3}$ ways of selecting three red balls from the $\binom{28}{3}$ ways of selecting three balls.